# Pygame - Alien Invasion: Making aliens shoot back

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm currently attempting to get my aliens to drop 'bombs' back at the player during game play. My current goal is to just get all aliens to drop bombs, then to eventually have random aliens drop bombs after a certain level.

[Currently is seems that all bombs are coming from the starting location of my first alien.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjmKY.jpg)

alien_invasion.py

```
import sys, pygame

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
from bombs import Bomb
from alien import Alien

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initlize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.settings.screen_width, 
                                            self.settings.screen_height))
        self.settings.screen_width = self.screen.get_rect().width
        self.settings.screen_height = self.screen.get_rect().height

        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.alien = Alien(self)

        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.bombs = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self._create_fleet()

        #Set our background color
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
        

    def run_game(self):
        """Start main loop for our game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()


            self.ship.update() 

            self._drop_bombs()
            self._update_bombs()
            
            self._update_aliens()
                
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to kepresses and mouse events."""
        #for each event in game capture that event
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #if player preses close, quit game
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            # if event is a key press
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        """respond to keydown events"""
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            sys.exit()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.ship.moving_right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.ship.moving_left = False

    def _drop_bombs(self):
        """drop bombs from alien ships"""
        new_bomb = Bomb(self)
        for alien in self.aliens:
            self.bombs.add(new_bomb)

    def _update_bombs(self):
        """update bombs positions and gets rid of old bombs"""
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.bombs.update()
        for bomb in self.bombs.copy():
            if bomb.rect.bottom >= self.screen_rect.bottom:
                self.bombs.remove(bomb)


    def _update_aliens(self):
        """update the position of the aliens"""
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()

        self._check_aliens_bottom()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        """create our fleet of aliens"""
        # creat an alien and fine the number that fits in a row
        # spacing between each alien is equal to one alien
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_x = self.settings.screen_width - (2 * alien_width)
        number_aliens_x = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

        # determine the number of rows that fit on the screen
        ship_height = self.ship.rect.height
        available_space_y = (self.settings.screen_height - 
                                (5 * alien_height) - ship_height)
        number_rows = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)

        # create a full fleet of aliens
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_x):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)


    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.x = alien_width + 2 * alien_width * alien_number
        alien.rect.x = alien.x
        alien.rect.y = 2 * alien_height + 2 * alien.rect.height * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien)

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        """respond if any aliens reach the edge"""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def _check_aliens_bottom(self):
        """check if any aliens have reached the bottom of the screen"""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
                self._ship_hit()
                break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        """drop entire fleet and change direction"""
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.y += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update images on screen and flip to the new screen."""
        #fill our background with our bg_color
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)

        #draw ship to screen
        self.ship.blitme()

        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()

        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)


        for bomb in self.bombs.sprites():
            bomb.draw_bomb()


        #Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        #this clears our previous screen and updates it to a new one
        #this gives our programe smooth movemnt
        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Make a game instance, and run the game
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

alien.py

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a sinlge alien in the fleet"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """initlize alien and set its starting position"""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # load alien image at set its rect
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # start each new alien at the top left of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        # store aliens exact position (decimal)
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

    def check_edges(self):
        """return true if alien is at edge of screen"""
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right or self.rect.left <= 0:
            return True

    def update(self):
        """move the alien to the right or left"""
        self.x += (self.settings.alien_speed *
                        self.settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

bombs.py

```
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bomb(Sprite):
    """create a bullet that is dropped by aliens"""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.color = self.settings.bullet_color

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.settings.bullet_width,
            self.settings.bullet_height)
        self.rect.midbottom = ai_game.alien.rect.midbottom

        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        """move bullet down screen"""
        self.y += self.settings.bullet_speed
        self.rect.y = self.y

    def draw_bomb(self):
        """draw bullet to screen"""
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

settings.py

```
class Settings:
    """A class to store our settings for Alien Invasion game."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initlize the games settings."""
        # screen settings
        self.screen_width = 1600
        self.screen_height = 900
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

        # ship settings
        self.ship_limit = 3

        # bullet settings
        self.bullet_width = 3
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = (60, 60, 60)
        self.bullets_allowed = 3

        # alien settings
        self.fleet_drop_speed = 10

        # how quickly the game speeds up
        self.speedup_scale = 1.1

        # how muct alien poits value increses
        self.score_scale = 1.5

        self.initialize_dynamic_settings()

    def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):
        """settings that change through the game"""
        self.ship_speed = 1.5
        self.bullet_speed = 1.5
        self.alien_speed = 0.5

        self.fleet_direction = 1

        # scoring
        self.alien_points = 50

    def increse_speed(self):
        """increse speed settings"""
        self.ship_speed *= self.speedup_scale
        self.bullet_speed *= self.speedup_scale
        self.alien_speed *= self.speedup_scale

        self.alien_points = int(self.alien_points * self.score_scale)
```

ship.py

```
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Ship(Sprite):
    """A class for managing our ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initlize the ship and set its starting position."""
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # load ship image and get its rect.(rect stands for rectangle)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

        # store a decimal value for the ship's horizontal position
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)

        # movement flags
        # we start our flag at false so the ship doesnt move by itself
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

    def update(self):
        """Update ships position based on our movement flags"""
        # update ship's x value, not its rectange
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.x += self.settings.ship_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
            self.x -= self.settings.ship_speed

        # update rect object for self.x
        self.rect.x = self.x

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at its current location."""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def center_ship(self):
        """center ship"""
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
```

How would I go about getting each alien to drop their own bomb?

Hopefully this follows minimal reproducible example better for you guys.

Comment: if all object would have the same functions with the same names - ie. `draw` instead of `draw_bomb` and `blitme` - then you could keep all of them on list and use `for`-loop to execute the same functions on all objects. And then `Alien` could add `Bomb` to this list and `for`-loop would draw like other objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to include the x y position of the bomb in the `__init__` of bombs:

```
class Bomb(sprite):
    def __init__(self, ai_game, x, y):
        # [...]

        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.settings.bullet_width,
            self.settings.bullet_height)

        self.y = y
```

and now in the creation of the bombs (in `_drop_bombs`), you need to include the x and y position of the alien:

```
class AlienInvasion:
    # [...]

    def _drop_bombs(self):
        """drop bombs from alien ships"""
        for alien in self.aliens:
            new_bomb = Bomb(self, alien.x, alien.y)  # top left of alien
            # do alien.x + 5 or something to drop the bomb in the middle
            self.bombs.add(new_bomb)
```

I would also recommend to include the x and y position of the alien in the `__init__` instead of modifying it afterwards.